# RewriteCond -d .htaccess failing but directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to conditionally rewrite the directory path of a URI if an override exists and the override directory exists in an Apache 2.2 .htaccess file running on RHEL5.

I am doing this by conditionally setting an environment variable to a directory and then  later I am checking if the environment variable is set and the directory exists. This is for a Drupal site but not sure that matters.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}                      qa-public.sample.com
RewriteRule ^ -                               [ENV=publicFiles:sites/qa-public.sample.com/files]
...
RewriteCond %{ENV:publicFiles}                !^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:publicFiles}                -d
RewriteRule ^sites/default/files(/.*)$        %{ENV:publicFiles}$1 [PT]
```

I turned on rewrite logging to level 7.

```
10.20.67.192 - - [27/Feb/2014:13:16:34 --0500] [qa-public.sample.com/sid#7f631331ecd8][rid#7f631360e568/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/qa-public/] RewriteCond: input='sites/qa-public.sample.com' pattern='!^$' => matched
10.20.67.192 - - [27/Feb/2014:13:16:34 --0500] [qa-public.sample.com/sid#7f631331ecd8][rid#7f631360e568/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/qa-public/] RewriteCond: input='sites/qa-public.sample.com' pattern='-d' => not-matched
```

I used the output of `perdir` and `input` to verify it exists. It is a symbolic link pointing to a directory.

```
$ ls -l /var/www/qa-public/sites/qa-public.sample.com/files
lrwxrwxrwx 1 XXXXXX YYYYYY 27 Feb 13 14:20 /var/www/qa-public/sites/qa-public.sample.com/files -> /usr/local/files-qa/
```

I have also tried `-l` and `-x`. I have also tried other non-linked directories.

I have tried adding a `/` before and/or after the directory in the `RewriteCond`.

I can remove the `-d` condition and Apache will serve the file.

Thanks,
Wes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:publicFiles} -d
```